# How to remove div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="1" class="delete_activity">x</a> 
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="2" class="delete_activity">x</a> 
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="3" class="delete_activity">x</a> 
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

After the click on "delete_activity" I need to remove the "row" div that have that link.
In the case the user click on X (href=1) i need to remove:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="1" class="delete_activity">x</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do it with JQuery?

Comment: Have you actually tried?  If so can we see what you produced?

Comment: i think you also need to delete from database or only from HTML. bcoz on page refresh. u'll see it again if you do it only with `jQuery`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do this is use `closest()`.

```
$('.delete_activity').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
```

Don't use `parents` (unless thats the behaviour you want).

`closest` will only remove the first element found up the DOM tree.

`parents` will remove ALL elements matched up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.delete_activity').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.row').remove();
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: this will remove the a tag only !

Comment: @poelinca - how do you figure?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".delete_activity").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).parents('.row').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('.delete_activity').click(function (e) { 
  $(this).parents('div.row').remove();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.delete_activity').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('row:first').remove();
});
```

Use first to get the first parent above!